# Kivy listview adding items overlapping

Tags: python, listview, kivy

When im adding items to the `kivy` list view `listitemlabel` from a file the spacing of the labels seems to overlap the new additions and i'm not sure from what part. When the list is blank at start and new additions are added the spacing doesnt overlap between labels yet if something is wrong with my `_reset_spopulate` then not sure how to fix.

```
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout  
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput 
from kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter import SimpleListAdapter 
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView, ListItemButton, ListItemLabel

class Controller(GridLayout):
    data = ['0','1','2']
    test_list=[]
    data0 = ['hello','2','3','2']
    data1 = ['world','e','r','young']
    data2 = ['1']
    all_list = []
    all_list.append(data0)
    all_list.append(data1)
    all_list.append(data2)
    info_data = []
    list_x = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Controller,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = 0

        self.my_list.adapter.bind(on_selection_change = self.selection_change)
        self.my_list.adapter.cls.deselected_color = (1,1,1,1)
        self.my_list.adapter.cls.selected_color = (1,0,1,1)

    def repopulate(self):
        if(hasattr(self.my_info, '_reset_spopulate')):
            self.my_info._reset_spopulate()

    def on_load_files(self):
        pass

    def on_enter(self):
        self.all_list[self.list_x].append(self.my_in.text)
        self.my_info.adapter.data.append(self.my_in.text)
        self.repopulate()

    def selection_change(self,adapter,*args):
        if len(adapter.selection)!=0:
            self.list_x=int(adapter.selection[0].text[0])
            #for x in xrange(0,len(self.all_list[self.list_x])):
            self.my_info.adapter.data = self.all_list[self.list_x]
                #self.my_info.adapter.data.append(self.all_list[self.list_x][x])
            self.repopulate()

    def load_test(self):
        with open('./data0.txt','r+') as d0:
            for line in d0.readlines():
                try:
                    self.data0.append(line)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.data0)):
                self.data0 = [i.strip('\r\n') for i in self.data0]

    def load_files(self):
        with open('./data0.txt','r+') as d0:
            for line in d0.readlines():
                try:
                    self.test_list.append(line)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.test_list)):
                self.test_list=[i.strip('\n') for i in self.test_list]

        self.data0 = self.test_list
        self.all_list.append(self.data0)

        with open('./data1.txt','r+') as d0:
            for line in d0.readlines():
                try:
                    self.test_list.append(line)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.test_list)):
                self.test_list=[i.strip('\n') for i in self.test_list]

        self.data1 = self.test_list
        self.all_list.append(self.data1)

        with open('./data2.txt','r+') as d2:
            for line in d2.readlines():
                try:
                    self.test_list.append(line)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.test_list)):
                self.test_list=[i.strip('\n') for i in self.test_list]

        self.data2 = self.test_list
        self.all_list.append(self.data2)

    def write_files(self):
        with open('./data0.txt','w+') as d0:
            d0.seek(0)
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.data0)):
                d0.write(self.data0[x]+'\n')
            d0.seek(0)
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.data0)):
                print d0.readline().strip('\n')

        with open('./data1.txt','w+') as d0:
            d0.seek(0)
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.data1)):
                d0.write(self.data1[x]+'\n')
            d0.seek(0)
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.data1)):
                print d0.readline().strip('\n')

        with open('./data2.txt','w+') as d2:
            d2.seek(0)
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.data2)):
                d2.write(self.data2[x]+'\n')
            d2.seek(0)
            for x in xrange(0,len(self.data2)):
                print d2.readline().strip('\n')

    def on_write_files(self):
        pass#self.write_files()


class NameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        controller = Controller()
        controller.load_test()
        return controller 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    NameApp().run()
```

Here is the name.kv

```
#:kivy 1.4.0
#:import label kivy.uix.label
#:import sla kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter
#:import la kivy.adapters.listadapter
#:import lib kivy.uix.listview

<Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'middle'

<Controller>:
    my_in:my_in_id
    my_info:my_info_id
    my_list:my_list_id
    cols:1
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text:'on_load_files()'
            size_hint:None,None
            size:100,30
            pos:100,100
            on_press:root.on_load_files()
        ListView:
            id:my_list_id
            size_hint:.2,.6
            size:00,400
            pos_hint:{'x':.2,'y':.2}
            pos:200,200
            adapter:
                la.ListAdapter(
                data=root.data,
                cls=lib.ListItemButton,
                selection_mode='single',
                allow_empty_selection=True
                )
        ListView:
            id:my_info_id
            size_hint: .4,.6
            pos:400,200
            adapter:
                la.ListAdapter(
                data=root.info_data,
                cls=lib.ListItemLabel,
                selection_mode='single',
                allow_empty_selection=True)

        Button:
            size_hint:None,None
            size:100,30
            pos:0,0
            text:'enter/clear'
            on_press:root.on_write_files()
        TextInput:
            size_hint:.8,None
            size:400,30
            pos:100,0
            background_color:0.2,0.2,0.2,1
            foreground_color:1,1,1,1
            id:my_in_id
            multiline:False
            text:'enter new item'
            on_text_validate:root.on_enter()
```

Answer (score 2):

using an args_converter and setting the height of the item in the list to not have it cut off the label or line is the way to fix this

```
args_converter = lambda row_index, x: {'text': '{0:^20}'.format(x), 'size_hint_y': None, 'height': 55},
```